# Why does the WiFi password dialogue not open up?

Tags: wireless

I see WiFi networks; but when I select one there is no dialogue to enter a password. So I have no WiFi, only wired connection.

The output of pgrep NetworkManager is: 951. Ubuntu version is 14.04

What can I do to get the password dialogue back?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running? What the output to `pgrep NetworkManager` is?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Comment: thank you Fabby. Done! Output is 951, ubuntu version is 14.04

Comment: As per User comment below the answer: **Linux GoBang is off topic here**.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit of overkill, but *the easiest way* of circumventing the problem you have: Install [another network Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD).

Steps to take:

1. Take a [full system backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) (You've just been promoted to user type 4!)
2. `sudo apt-get install -d --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome`

   Now is the time to stop and reflect and already test whether this already solved your problem.

   No?  OK, lets get on to the next step:
3. `sudo apt-get install wicd-gtk`
4. `sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager-gnome network-manager`

OK, so now you've got rid of the old network manager and have a new one.  Now you need to open it and configure your network:

1. Go to the dash and type `wicd` and click the sole icon there.
2. Voilà: now you just have to add the config for your network

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: hi Fabby, thank you very much for your answer! I'll definitely try this, but before I do there's a couple things worrying me: I'm not in gnome ubuntu nor unity, but in something called [gobang](http://gobangos.sourceforge.net/), some kind of crunchbang style ubuntu. So I don't have any "dash", and maybe "network-manager-gnome" is not what I have installed, since I have no gnome desktop enviroment?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't use gnome...  Did the other stuff help?  If yes, don't forget to click the ☑ next to the answer... If you have any forther questions, do not hesitate [to ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!  **;-)**